# Do the discs of observed solar systems have random orientations?

Tags: observational-astronomy

Is there any bias in the orientation of solar systems?

Comment: Good question. I think the best answer is still given [here](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/21193/5264) (in which case your question should be closed as a duplicate), but perhaps Rob Jeffries might have some updates (?).

Comment: Some additional insight might come from considering the orientations of protoplanetary disks in young (e.g., pre-main-sequence) stars; as far as I know these are random.